# In Powershell, how to retrieve existing policy settings (Win8.1/server 2012 r2 core)

Tags: powershell, wmi, wmi-query, wmic, local-security-policy

Is it possible in Powershell (using Get-WmiObject or similar) to retrieve existing policy setting on local, single win 8.1 or server 2012 R2 core machine?

In SecPol the policy I want to retrieve the setting for is
"Local Policies" -> "User Rights Assignment" -> "Log on as a service"

I already know I can use secedit /export to dump the data into a config file, was wondering if there was a more direct way such as Get-WmiObject that would just return the object and property in question to stdout.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Boe Prox has written [a module for this called PoshPrivilege](http://learn-powershell.net/2015/06/03/managing-privileges-using-poshprivilege/).

Using this module, you would use the following:

```powershell
Get-Privilege -Privilege SeServiceLogonRight
```

Comment: Thx for answering!  Is it possible to perform that w/o the installation of any additional modules and such?

Comment: Well, you could look at [the source code for the module](https://github.com/proxb/PoshPrivilege) to see how he did it, but I suspect you're not going to want to go through all that. To my knowledge there is no existing direct cmdlet. If there are WMI calls, I am not aware of them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer in any case!  I ended up just grepping for the string I wanted to check from the .cfg file I exported using secedit.